# Do the suffixes -ic and -ous have the same meaning?

Tags: meaning, difference, suffixes

When a word can use both of those suffixes, does it have the same meaning?

For example, 'polysemic' and 'polysemous'. Both from the noun 'polysemy'.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In chemistry, such terms **almost** always have distinct meanings.  For example, ferric refers to compounds of Fe³⁺ and ferrous to compounds of Fe²⁺, nitric oxide is NO and nitrous oxide is N₂O, and so on. (Note: I just thought of *anhydrous*/*anhydric*, which is an exception.)  In other sciences, an *-ic* and an *-ous* form sometimes are synonyms (like *achromous*/*achromic*), and sometimes aren’t (like *autonomic*/*autonomous*).

Non-technical *-ic*/*-ous* or *-ic*/*-ious* pairs are often, but not always, synonyms (like *euphoric*/*euphorious*).  There are also some words whose final syllable coincidentally happens to be *-ous* or *-ic* and also happen to have a corresponding *-ic* or *-ous* word, such as *arsenic*/*arsenious* or *arsenous*, and *generic*/*generous*.  (Thanks to other users for sharing better examples!)

Comment: And, by the way, yes, *polysemic* and *polysemous* are synonymous.

Comment: @PaulTanenbaum i did not know that!

Comment: What does ETA mean? It certainly isn't "Estimated Time to Arrival" here.

Comment: I don’t really understand the last sentence. _Arsenous_ and _autologic_ do not exist, as far as I know. What corresponding forms are you referring to? @iBug It means ‘Edited To Add’.

Comment: @iBug some people seem to use it to mean "Edited to Add".

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet It’s more commonly spelled *arsenious*, but the spelling *arsenous acid* also exists.

Comment: In other words "Well yes, but actually no." Or, for a fuller answer, grammatically speaking for the formation of words they are equivalent, but in chemistry they have distinct meanings, and once the words are formed they can drift in meaning.

Comment: Current IUPAC nomenclature prefers terms like "iron (III) oxide" (rust) versus "iron (II) oxide" (wüstite) instead of the *-ic* and *-ous* forms.  However, the similar distinction between *-ate* and *-ite* in oxyanions is still around.

Answer (score 16):

No, they need not have the same meaning. For example, "generous" and "generic" share a root but have very different meanings (from M-W) despite bearing those suffixes:

[generous](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/generous): "liberal in giving : OPENHANDED" (among other meanings)

[generic](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/generic): "relating to or characteristic of a whole group or class : GENERAL" (among other meanings)

Another answer gives good examples from chemistry.

Comment: And here I was trying to think of a better example than *autologous*.

Comment: @Davislor I saw that but couldn't figure it out. Are you suggesting that there's also a word "autologic"? I looked [in Onelook](https://onelook.com/?w=autologic&ls=a) but couldn't find any dictionary entry for it.

Comment: It’s not in the dictionary, but I think I’ve seen it in the context of VLSI. In any case, generous/generic is a much better example!

Comment: Also: autonomic vs autonomous.

Comment: But except in chemistry, there is not a systematic difference in meaning.

Comment: @ColinFine Correct, it's unpredictable.

Comment: @LearningEnglish Although Davislor's answer is a good and interesting one, I think this answer serves better as the correct one.

Comment: @ColinFine Maybe, but is there a systematous meaning?